# newDevicesURL property of wurfl element in config file not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, 51degrees

`newDevicesURL` is mentioned as optional. Even if we remove it or set `newDevicesURL=""` , it internally calls the `http://devices.51degrees.mobi/new.ashx` service. This was observed in fiddler. Please suggest on how can I avoid these calls at all. I do not want my application to have any external calls to any service or application.

Please revert back soon.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been removed in the latest version of the 51Degrees API. You can find the updated documentation [here](http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Documentation/Foundation.aspx?CATReferrer=1765) and get the download in the products section [here](http://51degrees.mobi/Products/Overview.aspx?CATReferrer=1765). Hope this helps.